# SignalR disconnection after auto AD logout

Tags: authentication, asp-classic, signalr

I'm having the following issue with my project implementing SignalR. 
My users are authenticated through ASP regular authentication. (based on the AD base)

***When the authentication timeout is reached, the connection between javascript and the hub fails.
I'm wondering what is the good way to handle that.*** (event (which one?) + reconnection?)

Thank you very much in advance

****Data:****

***In chrome debug:***

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://mySite:81/Project/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&con...
```

***IIS log:***

***When authentication is still active:***

```
2013-04-23 10:27:07 IP POST /Project/signalr/send transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=RRBKQRnC_KsWBfxuGTXbfsvipbDWWFRVSodpXmW2-CS-GniKtxx69WbAJXURCLns_CfNJDmSZUI3v9LLslqWYy5pvzA1lzCcl9nWx1ufAOB69l8CFTPySNZWzJrVs-VKIb34vjHq5qi8qfms-LFg6j_zwO9WA4vguRu1LdPxY2I2p09v6X_PE7tfCXnIS4vS0 81 thomas.dupuis MYIP Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.22+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/25.0.1364.160+Safari/537.22 200 0 0 2252
```

***When authentication is not active anymore:***

```
2013-04-23 10:28:39 IP POST /Project/signalr/send transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=RRBKQRnC_KsWBfxuGTXbfsvipbDWWFRVSodpXmW2-CS-GniKtxx69WbAJXURCLns_CfNJDmSZUI3v9LLslqWYy5pvzA1lzCcl9nWx1ufAOB69l8CFTPySNZWzJrVs-VKIb34vjHq5qi8qfms-LFg6j_zwO9WA4vguRu1LdPxY2I2p09v6X_PE7tfCXnIS4vS0 81 - MYIP Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.22+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/25.0.1364.160+Safari/537.22 500 0 0 209
```

We can see first log contains my user ID (thomas.dupuis), not the second. (First one gets 200 http whereas the second gets 500 error internal server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're timing out authentication you need to have the client do a hard re-start, aka call $.connection.hub.stop() and then $.connection.hub.start().  Authentication credentials cannot be modified while a SignalR connection is active.